# How to concatenate string in hyperlink function

Tags: openoffice-calc

I would like to add a column in my OpenOffice Calc spreadsheet.
In particular, this column should contain a hyperlink to a query on Google.

For example: if in A1 I have the string "The gladiator", I would like have column B1:

```
"www.google.it?q=The Gladiator"
```

So I can click and open the browser to see how that "film" is (yes, it is a simple film database).

Thank you!

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 3):

You have two options:

[The `&` operator](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Operators):

```
=hyperlink("http://www.google.com/search?q="&A1)
```

or [the `concatenate()` function](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_CONCATENATE_function):

```
=hyperlink(CONCATENATE("http://www.google.com/search?q="; A1))
```

The `HYPERLINK()` function handles URL encoding for you.

Answer (score 1):

Excellent Answer: Use `&` or `Concatenate` function.

Let me add, the proper connector is semi-colon, not comma...

Also, I would recommend using the film title as the celltext, to avoid having the literal hyperlink display in the column b cell.

```
=hyperlink("http...?q="&a1;a1)

=hyperlink(CONCATENTATE("http...?q=";a1);a1)
```

I am using this exact function (different target URL) and am trying to get the new page to launch in the same window as the previous, to avoid having to click the X in the corner (talk about lazy).